# EF Core Not Updating Table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to update two tables that are related using Entity Framework Core 3.1. Only the first table (`Paycheck`) is updated. The second table (`Tax`) is not updated but produces no error. What am I doing wrong?

I have two related database tables that look like this:

```
**Paycheck Table**
PaycheckId int  (Primary Key)
TaxId      int  (Foreign Key)
Deleted    bool

**Tax Table**
TaxId      int   (Primary Key)
Deleted    bool
```

When the following method is called I want to set the `Deleted` field in each table to true. The `Deleted` field in the `Paycheck` table is set to true as expected but the `Deleted` field in the `Tax` table does not get set to true and I'm not sure why.

```
public void DeletePaycheck(int PaycheckID)
{
     using (var context = new FinancialContext())
     {
            // Get TaxId from Paycheck Table
            var taxId = context.Paycheck
                        .Where(t => t.PaycheckId == PaycheckID)
                        .Select(t => t.TaxId)
                        .Single();


            var paycheckEntity = 
                  context.Paycheck.FirstOrDefault(i => i.PaycheckId == PaycheckID);

            var taxEntity = context.Paycheck
                            .Include(t => t.Tax)
                            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaxId == taxId);

            if (paycheckEntity != null)
                    paycheckEntity.Deleted = true;

            if (taxEntity != null)
                    taxEntity.Deleted = true;

           context.SaveChanges();
     }
```

Comment: So, when you drop a beak point and debug this, are you getting the values you expect for taxId and taxEnttity?  Also, why are you querying for the Tax entity separately and not as an "include" with the Paycheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason that your code is not working, is this part:

```
var taxEntity = context.Paycheck
     .Include(t => t.Tax)
     .FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaxId == taxId);
```

taxEntity is an instance of `Paycheck`, hence you're setting `Deleted = true` on a random `Paycheck` instance with specified TaxId instead of a `Tax` instance.

The whole logic may be replaced by

```
var paycheck = context.Paycheck
     .Include(it => it.Tax)
     .SingleOrDefault(it => it.PaycheckId == PaycheckID);

if (paycheck != null) 
{
    paycheck.Deleted = true;

    if (paycheck.Tax != null) 
    {
        paycheck.Tax.Deleted = true;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If `Tax` is non-nullable, it may be simplified further.

Comment: That works exactly as I was hoping. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This should help.

```
context.Update(paycheckEntity);
context.Update(taxEntity);
context.SaveChanges();
```